# how to use tesseract OCR for windows XP for eclipse?

Tags: android, cygwin, ocr, android-ndk

I am trying to develop my first OCR app using tesseract. I'm developing under Windows XP using Eclipse and targeting Android 2.1+

1. do i need cygwin?
2. do i need the android ndk?

--->Through vast research and consultation, I realize that you dont need cygwin or ndk either. But still, the code and procedure on Gautams blog gives error. I tried building the app and ended but with an application package file that does nothing but force closes when I press the "OCR!" button on the app. Any idea??

Comment: Following the links in the link **you** provided leads to here: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you do not need Cygwin.
2. Yes, you need to have the Android NDK installed.

[Gautam's tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) is the best tutorial for using Tesseract OCR on Android.